# Inserting mysql values from 'submit' button in PHP doesn't work as expect

Tags: php, mysql, insert, submit

I have two tables:

- 'courses' with these fields:COURSE_ID(auto
  increment),start_date,end_date,title
- 'courses_students' with these    fields:ID(auto
  increment),COURSE_ID,STUDENT_ID.

I want to insert some values in my mysql table called "courses_students" from my other table called "courses".
Users can see in a page the data from 'courses'(courses names,starting dates,ending dates) and they must select which course they want to attend,by clicking the button 'attent course'.

Everytime someone clicks the submit button,the values are inserted in courses_students table,but not correctly.The problem is that everytime,the COURSE_ID from 'courses_students' has the value of the last COURSE_ID from 'courses'.And,other strange problem is that the values are inserted twice,everytime.

This is the code:

```
<?php 

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$link){
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

mysql_selectdb("db");

?>
<ul>
<?php


$sql = "SELECT * FROM courses";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($file = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>';

    $STUDENT_ID = $_SESSION['ID'];  
    $COURSE_ID = $file['COURSE_ID'];  //**It dislays the CORRECT ID for each course!**
    echo 'the course id: ' .$COURSE_ID;
    echo 'course name: ' .$file['title'];
    echo 'Starting: ' .$file['start_date'];
    echo ' ending: '.$file['end_date'];
    echo '<form action="lista_cursuri.php" method="post"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="attent course!"> </form>';
    echo '</li>';



} 

?>
</ul>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `courses_students` (COURSE_ID,STUDENT_ID) VALUES ($COURSE_ID,$STUDENT_ID)";
$result = mysql_query($sql1);

}

?>
```

I can't manage to see where the problem is.Maybe this is not the correct procedure.

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: where in this code are you updating a table?

Comment: One thing, you're using sessions `$_SESSION['ID']`. Is `session_start();` include in your file(s) ? It's not posted/mentioned in your question. This is required and will not work otherwise. @AdiCrainic

Comment: @JohnConde .i don't receive any error.Values are inserted but,as i said,the problem is with course_id field.

Comment: @Clustermagnet  i don't want to update.just inserting vales when the submit button is clicked

Comment: @AdiCrainic ok, and i dont see where you have this code :)

Comment: You print on screen info about every course in the table....and one form for every course....but your are not storing the right course id in an input type hidden field...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes,the session_start is included.Student_ID  is inserted correctly.

**SESSION ID has the values from another table called users.Users,aften they login,they acces this page.**

Comment: @RobertRozas

When i print the COURSES_ID,it displays the correct ID for each course

Comment: Yes, but you are not storing them in the form.

Comment: May not fix your problem, but from what I've seen in other similar cases, the values are set inside quotes, which you don't have. Try using `VALUES ('$COURSE_ID','$STUDENT_ID')` @AdiCrainic

Comment: How are you receiving values of $COURSE_ID on insert page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Part 1:

```
while($file = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>';

$STUDENT_ID = $_SESSION['ID'];  
$COURSE_ID = $file['COURSE_ID'];
echo 'the course id: ' .$COURSE_ID;
echo 'course name: ' .$file['title'];
echo 'Starting: ' .$file['start_date'];
echo ' ending: '.$file['end_date'];
echo "<form action='lista_cursuri.php' method='post'> 
      <input type='hidden' name='courseid' value='".$COURSE_ID."' >
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value='attent course!''> </form>";
echo '</li>';

}
```

Part 2:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $course = $_POST['courseid'];
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `courses_students` (COURSE_ID,STUDENT_ID) VALUES     ($course,$STUDENT_ID)";
  $result = mysql_query($sql1);

}
```

Comment: **It worked!** 

Thank you very much...it was very important to manage this!

Answer (score 3):

Salut

Change  `mysql_fetch_array` which is a multidimensional array once numerically indexed and once by field name which gives you double results  to `mysql_fetch_assoc`

and `$COURSE_ID` is always last because for each loop it is overwritten

Comment: Buna,

Thanks,

after changing,it inserts now the values only one time.But the bigges problem remains.I will check the solution from the others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `courses_students` (COURSE_ID,STUDENT_ID) 
VALUES ('".$COURSE_ID."','".$STUDENT_ID."')"; $result = mysql_query($sql1);
```

Comment: Use proper indents next time you give an answer (I edited it). Otherwise your code doesn't "look" like code ;-)

Comment: No problemo, I understand. You can try this trick. Use 4 spaces followed by your 1st line of code, should work.